# directory index of "/var/www/html/" is forbidden in container nginx with another container php-fpm

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx, networking, server

why in this https get:

```
10.0.2.2 - - [09/Sep/2023:18:04:23 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 199 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

in this nginx server:

```
server {
    server_name dcruz-na.42.fr www.dcruz-na.42.fr;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/dcruz-na.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/dcruz-na.key;
    ssl_ciphers 'TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384';

    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
        

    root /var/www/html;
    
    index index.php;
    
    location / {
        autoindex off;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }
        
    location ~ [^/]\\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_index index.php;
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass wordpress:9000;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

the server returns 403 forbidden por este error en los  log: `2023/09/09 18:04:23 [error] 7#7: *5 directory index of "/var/www/html/" is forbidden, client: 10.0.2.2, server: dcruz-na.42.fr, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"`

I want php-fpm which is in the container wordpress:9000 to serve me the wordpress php files, the index.php when get /

Comment: Please write your question in English, as [Stack Overflow is an English only site.](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676). There are other versions of Stack Overflow in [Português](//pt.stackoverflow.com), [Español](//es.stackoverflow.com), [русский](//ru.stackoverflow.com), and [日本語](//ja.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: The site you need is [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: I already changed it to english

Comment: Good. [​](https://google.com)

Answer (score -1):

The error message "directory index of /var/www/html/ is forbidden" means that the web server (Nginx) is configured to not allow browsing the contents of the directory /var/www/html/. This can be caused by a number of things, such as:

- There is no index.html file in the directory.
- The directory is not owned by the web server user.
- The directory permissions are not set to allow the web server user to read and execute files.

To fix this error, you need to make sure that the following conditions are met:

- There is an index.html file in the directory /var/www/html/.
- The directory is owned by the web server user.
- The directory permissions are set to allow the web server user to read and execute files.

You can check the ownership and permissions of the directory using the following commands:

```
ls -l /var/www/html/
```

If the directory is not owned by the web server user, you can change the ownership using the following command:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/
```

If the directory permissions are not set to allow the web server user to read and execute files, you can change the permissions using the following command:

```
chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/
```

Once you have made sure that the above conditions are met, the error message should go away.

Here are some additional things to check:

- Make sure that the Nginx configuration file is correctly configured to serve the contents of the directory /var/www/html/.
- Make sure that the PHP-FPM configuration file is correctly configured to allow the web server to execute PHP scripts.

If you are still having trouble, you can consult the documentation for Nginx and PHP-FPM for more information.

Comment: But php-fpm is in another docker container, so the webserver content is in the var/www/html of the other server, not in the one of the nginx, right?